# Webdriverio 8 performance issues when running tests in parallel

Tags: webdriver-io

We have several tests implemented with webdriverio in our framework and they were working fine when running in parallel before the update to version 8. Now, as soon as reaching 6 tests running in parallel, there is a terrible drop in performance. Several tests even fail to run in the browser - it's like just the browser launches and that's it. All of the tests run fine if they are run one by one. Had anyone faced this and is there a workaround?